Should I use a 45 degree or two 90s to connect sink to p-trap?
I have a vanity cabinet with a bathroom sink. Diagram is a side view with the wall in thick black. There's a sliding drawer at the bottom. The sink drain (1 in diagram) is above the drawer (when it's closed). The drain pipe coming from the wall (2 in diagram) is behind the drawer. There is enough room to put in a p-trap if I align it parallel to the wall. Since the p-trap cannot be placed directly below the sink drain, what's the best way to connect the two?
I've read that flexible connectors are prone to clogging, so I'd prefer to do regular rigid 1.5 inch ABS. I think my two main options are to either put in a straight pipe sloped 45 degrees OR two 90 elbows with a horizontal run from the sink to get past the drawer and then drop vertically into the p-trap. Which of these is preferable in terms of drainage? Are there other options I haven't thought of?


the less elbows you have the better the flow

The answer is: we don't have enough information.  Does your sink drain line up with the stub into the wall, or is it offset?  How much elevation difference is there between the bottom of the sink and the top of the drawer back, and between the bottom of the sink drain and the stub?  How much horizontal difference is there between the bottom of the sink drain and the stub?

Either one will work. Just make sure to make all the connections slip-joint so that you can disassemble it quickly in case of clogs.
The best option is, of course, to open up the wall and raise the drain coming from the wall. Remove the drywall to see how it looks. It might be a simple job, or impossible, depending on how things are behind the wall.

The wall is tiled, raising the drain all the way to the vent stack is going to be too much work and money. My plan is to slip-joint at the sink and have a threaded union at the p-trap, while gluing in-between.

Get a "shifted" P trap that will do what you want, for example IKEA RANNILEN (photo below), or ask the shop that sold you the furniture: if it is designed to put a sink on top and it has a drawer, they probably have a p-trap that will work with it!

Aqua Bagno from Amazon (I wouldn't buy noname brands from amazon though, but I still include the photo for inspiration):

Or something like that (I don't think this style is available in the US)


Isn't this the same as just putting in two 90 elbows? Any reason to buy a pre-made "shifted" p-trap as opposed to simply gluing some ABS together to achieve the same result?

It's the same but it comes with the screw fitting that is compatible with the sink's drain.

It sounds like you bought the wrong cabinet for this project.  The right thing to do in that case is re-measure, get it right this time, and go back to the store to find a cabinet that will fit.
Another option if you're planning to remodel the bathroom would be to open up the wall and re-design the drain.
If you really want to hack together a solution for this cabinet that doesn't fit, consider modifying or removing the drawer so that it has appropriate space for the trap.  I hesitate to even suggest this because it's generally easier and will look better to just get a new cabinet.
Flexible "accordion" pipes are a clear indication of the worst possible quality of building maintenance and they raise immediate concerns during inspections.
